# Android images for different screens

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-screen-support

I'm developing an Android app which uses a number of images and icons.
In order to prevent the device to work hard and run out of memory, I want to create multiple images for each screen size.
My question is: Do I need to measure **exactly** what dp I want and then convert it to pixels?
Sometimes it's hard to know exactly the size of the image in dp- for instance if it's width is `match_parent` and there's margin etc.

How can I solve this problem?
I would be glad for guidance on how to do this the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create images *for each screen size*, but rather *for each screen density*. So you will need five different files for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi (if you don't want to support some of these, just don't put the file in the corresponding folder). The algorithm is the following: take your image and put it to the 'xxxhdpi' folder. Then resize it, so it looks as you want on a device with the xxxhdpi density screen. Then resize your image for other densities using the following ratios:

```
mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
1    | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4
```

For example, to get the size of your mdpi image, divide a width and a height of the xxxhdpi image by four.

Comment: Thanks. My questions is: For the xxxhdpi image (and for the others), do I need to know exactly what size it should be in order to save memory, or it doesn't need to be exact? Also, what about images that I use center crop, which their real size is bigger than the ImageView?

Comment: You cannot know the exact size of an image, because it will be used on different devices with different screens. So if your image fills parent horizontally, just make sure, its width is at least equal to the screen width of a phone with the largest screen (for example, Pixel XL, which is 1440 px) your app can be installed on. But if your ImageView is 50 dp, for example, your xxxhdpi image should have a width of 200 px.

Comment: OK. In terms of memory, do you think it matters if the image is a bit larger than the imageview size?

Comment: I don't think it's noticeable, but you can always check the memory usage in Android Studio.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!